# Most of the books explain it + singular or plural

Tags: grammatical-number, pronouns

Should the following be singular or plural?

> Most of the books explain it in a way **that's** difficult to understand.

Since *books* are plural, shouldn't the part in bold be also plural?

Comment: it refers to the notion being explained. What is difficult to understand? It is not the books. It is what is explained therein. Btw, you've written *explian* instead of *explain*.

Comment: Passing thought; unless all the books explain it the same way, this should be *ways that are difficult to understand*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it is a contraction of *that is*.  The verb isn't agreeing with *books*, it's agreeing with *way*.

Answer (score 3):

The way it is written is correct. "That's" (that is) refers to the *way*, which is singular, not the books.